# Struts 2 ApplicationResources.properties error

Tags: struts2

I am using struts2 for my application.

```
<s:submit cssClass="button" key="btn.search" tabindex="12" />
```

in ApplicationResources.properties file i have

```
btn.search = Go
```

and i am getting error while submitting the page,

```
OgnlValueStac W com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn 
  Error setting expression 'btn.search' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@14f414f4'
  ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "search", [Ljava.lang.String;@14f414f4)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key` attribute is a shorthand for *both* the `name` and `value` attributes.

Using `key` means you're assuming a property named `btn.search`.

While you *may* set a value to the results of a text property lookup, you can also use it directly:

```
<s:submit value="%{getText('btn.search')}" />
```

Comment: As a note, this will require that the action is a `TextProvider`, such as by extending `ActionSupport`.  The `<s:text/>` tag does not require a TextProvider for accessing the `struts.custom.i18n.resources`.

Comment: @rees Yep. Although it's pretty rare an action *doesn't* extend that.

Comment: Yes, but I need the rep points, so I'm trying to shoot holes in your answer.  You also left out the asker's `cssClass="button"` and `tabindex="12"`, whereas my solution was copy-and-paste ready and would work even if the asker, for whatever reason, was not extending `ActionSupport`.  :D

Comment: @rees Yes, I left them out, because they're not relevant to the answer. (And putting classes on individual elements is rarely the cleanest solution anyway.)

Comment: @rees Also, I'd recommend aiming to gain rep by having complete answers, rather by attempting to tear down someone else's--your answer was fine on its own (modulo the guessing, which you edited out) and the verbosity of the extra set. Multiple users may get rep for any given question--this is not a zero-sum game. You'd have to jump through a lot of hoops to use an S2 form *without* a text provider if you're using message resources and expect coherent labels, though--strikes me as unlikely, or silly at the least.

Comment: Easy Dave! I guess I failed to successfully communicate the intended tongue-in-cheek tone on my last comment.  Also, as someone that has spent most of my (brief) career so far maintaining and upgrading existing apps, I've quickly learned to assume very little about the programming approach of others.  Hell, I learned half of what I know about Struts2 by reading your answers!

Comment: @rees Uh oh, 'cuz I only know about a quarter of what everyone thinks I know, which means you only learned an eighth of what you thought you did.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` is being submitted as a parameter and OGNL is trying to get an object named `btn` from the `ValueStack` to set the parameter by calling `getBtn().setSearch("");`, but, since you have no btn object in the stack, the null target exception is occurring.

This should work:

```
<s:set name="buttonText"><s:text name="btn.search"/></s:set>
<s:submit cssClass="button" value="%{#buttonText}" tabindex="12"/>
```

Or, as Dave has pointed out in his answer, this should work as well if your action class extends `ActionSupport`:

```
<s:submit cssClass="button" value="%{getText('btn.search')}" tabindex="12"/>
```